# Telethon: Post comments as a group in chat connected to a channel

Tags: telegram, telethon

I use telethon to monitor different channels and select the ones with biggest engagement (like comments, likes etc) and forward them to another channel.

I would like to post a comment like "Congrats, your post was selected as a top post today" but I would like to do that as a channel, not as a user (like you can do from Telegram OSX Client).

How can I do that with code?

Thank you.